# In xaml or in code is there a way to reuse brush definitions with varied parameters?

Tags: .net, wpf

In a control I have a number of brush which are defined like this:

```
<VisualBrush x:Key="hatchedBarBrush_1" TileMode="Tile" Viewport="0,0,5,5" ViewportUnits="Absolute"
    Viewbox="0,0,5,5" ViewboxUnits="Absolute" po:Freeze="True">
    <VisualBrush.Visual>
        <Grid Background="#46768c">
            <Path Data="M 0 5 L 5 0 M -2 2 L 2 -2 M 3 7 L 7 3" Stroke="#80ffffff" 
        StrokeEndLineCap="Square" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" />
        </Grid>
    </VisualBrush.Visual>
</VisualBrush>
```

The only difference between each brush is the background color for the grid element. Is there a way reuse the definition for each brush, and just vary the background color for each instance?

Comment: @ AnjumSKhan - thanks, can you please post a short example as xaml code?

Answer (score -1):

Code is self exlanatory, I did it the way you want.

```
    <Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>

          <VisualBrush x:Key="BrushKey" TileMode="Tile" Viewport="0,0,5,5" ViewportUnits="Absolute"
                                        Viewbox="0,0,5,5" ViewboxUnits="Absolute" >
            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="Grid">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#46768c"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ChangeColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding BrushColor}"/>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                                </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>                                                   
                    </Grid.Style>
                                    <Path Data="M 0 5 L 5 0 M -2 2 L 2 -2 M 3 7 L 7 3" Stroke="#80ffffff" 
                StrokeEndLineCap="Square" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" />
                    </Grid>
            </VisualBrush.Visual>
        </VisualBrush>

    </Window.Resources>


    <Grid Width="300" Height="300" Background="{StaticResource BrushKey}">

        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="63,42,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click_1"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {


        public Color BrushColor
        {
            get { return (Color)GetValue(BrushColorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(BrushColorProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for BrushColor.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty BrushColorProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("BrushColor", typeof(Color), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(Colors.Red));





        public bool ChangeColor
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(ChangeColorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ChangeColorProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ChangeColor.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ChangeColorProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ChangeColor", typeof(bool), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(false));




        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ChangeColor = true;
            BrushColor = Colors.PaleGreen;
        }
    }

}
```